# Hibernate logs from console as exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate in my web app on Spring. My methods in controller using try catch block and if everything is okay I set redirect parameter "success == true" and if something gone wrong the I use "error == true".
It works. But sometimes in my console hibernate shows me warning for example like this:

```
2017-01-28 19:13:44.253  WARN 4532 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2017-01-28 19:13:44.253 ERROR 4532 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter   : Duplicate entry
```

I just want to catch these warnings in try catch block because if I try to add new entry to DB with - in this case - duplicate entry then in try catch block everything is accepted and I got information "Operation succesfull" but it is not. 
I tried to catch differents exceptions like SQLException, HibernateException, even general - Exception. But it doesn't work. For operations like add, update, delete entries I use 'void' methods so I can't return some value.

Is it possible to catch these warnings/errors from console and how?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/adduserdb", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUserToDb(@ModelAttribute(value="userform") User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        try {
            userService.createBasicUser(user);  
            redirectAttributes.addAttribute("success", true);

            return "redirect:/admin/user/adduser";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            redirectAttributes.addAttribute("error", true);

            return "redirect:/admin/user/adduser";
        }
    }
```

Here is example for one of my methods how I do that but it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is indeed raised? There would be a difference between "catch not catching it" and "nothing to catch". Maybe userService handles it?

Answer (score 1):

Printing these errors are default nature of hibernate. If all you want is to hide the logs, you can disable logs for the below package. In spring boot that would be like

```
logger.level.org.hibernate.util=OFF
```

However this is not advised as other relevant logs may get unnoticed.

Instead in your case, you can do a check if the record already exist before doing the insert, thus avoid the need for the error itself.

```
boolean isUserExist = userService.isUserExist(user.getName());
if(!isUserExist){
    userService.createBasicUser(user);  
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("success", true)
else {
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("error", true);
    return "redirect:/admin/user/adduser";
}
```

While there may be a chance that another user gets added between both the service calls, this can be handled as a special case using a global exception handler that would show a generic error message as this is less likely (depending on the application)

Comment: This is something what I want but not completly. In this case I always have to check if user or other object exist in DB what mean next sql query to db. Hibernate always when something gone wrong throw HibernateException - even in this case with duplicate entry. Problem is that I can't catch this exception. My DAO methods use: "throws HibernateException" but in controller this exception even general "Exception" do not catch this. This is my real problem.

Comment: you can find the exact class of Exception by printing `exception.getClass()`, and then modify your code to catch that. but this exception will be a wrapper of the actual exception.. also by using try catch, you are heavily relying on spring's transactional nature (ability to rollback), but that is not a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the hibernate warnings you can set the log level of hibernate to info.

in your application.properties add this:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

in xml its:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

Comment: "If we set logging level to INFO, then application can log messages with scopes - INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL." - https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/logging-levels-in-log4j/